# Group records only if it have intersected periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this

```
   declare @data table
    (
        id int not null,
        groupid int not null,
        startDate datetime not null,
        endDate datetime not null   
    )


insert into @data values
(1, 1, '20150101', '20150131'),
(2, 1, '20150114', '20150131'),
(3, 1, '20150201', '20150228');
```

and my current selecting statement is:

```
select groupid, 'some data', min(id), count(*)
from @data
group by groupid
```

But now I need to group records if it have intersected periods

desired result:

```
1, 'some data', 1, 2
1, 'some data', 3, 1
```

Is someone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by intersected periods?  Do you mean having the same start **and** end date, or just that the periods overlap?

Comment: I supose the overlap is correct.
In sample data that I showed first two rows have date that included in both date range so this rows go to one group. The other row not overlaps to some else. So it go to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to identify the beginning of each group -- because it doesn't overlap with the previous one.  Then, count the number of these as a group identifier.

```
with overlaps as (
      select id
      from @data d
      where not exists (select 1
                        from @data d2
                        where d.groupid = d2.groupid and
                              d.startDate >= d2.startDate and
                              d.startDate < d2.endDate
                       )
     ),
     groups as (
      select d.*,
             count(o.id) over (partition by groupid
                               order by d.startDate) as grpnum
      from @data d left join
           overlaps o
           on d.id = o.id
     )
select groupid, min(id), count(*),
       min(startDate) as startDate, max(endDate) as endDate
from groups
group by grpnum, groupid;
```

Notes:  This is using cumulative counts, which are available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can do something similar with a correlated subquery or `apply` in earlier versions.

Also, this query assumes that the start dates are unique.  If they are not, the query can be tweaked, but the logic becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for idea, that works with little modifications!
with notHaveIntersections as (
...
                        where 
       d.id != d2.id and
       d.groupid = d2.groupid and
                            d.startDate <= d2.endDate and d.endDate >=  d2.startDate)